# ASP.net web server not logging on

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, authentication, web-config

I have inherited a ASP.net site, and I've made some changes too to some of the VB code and CSS, and have hosted it on a FTP. It uses an SQL DB to allow users to log in and calls stored procedures.

The site complies with no errors, and allows me to log in as a user, and can works perfectly on testing.

However, once uploaded to the FTP, it no longer allows me to log in as a user. It hangs for a while, and then returns a message saying that the password is wrong, despite it being correct. It doesn't throw an error message, and I think I've narrowed it down to something to do with the Web.config file, but I'm at a loss as how it's not working, especially with the lack of error messages being thrown.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
        Visual Basic options:
        Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
        where data loss can occur. 
        Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
</compilation>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <clear/>
            <add namespace="System"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
            <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
            <add namespace="System.Text"/>
            <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Removed the ASP Classic tag, only related to .NET

Comment: Can you include some relevant line from the `web.config` in your answer? Without seeing any code it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Okay I'll edit and include the code

Comment: Wild guess, but `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` tells me you need to login with a valid Windows User Account on the FTP location. This is probably a different PC, so maybe u are not known as a user there?

Comment: Hmm okay. Would the file work without     <authentication mode="Windows"/>?

Comment: Not my field of expertise. Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx) to an MSDN article about it. Or search on StackOverflow for question on `.net authentication mode`, must be more people that had issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since got hosting elsewhere and that seems to have done the trick, so I think the problem was down to the host's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be a configuration in IIS if (assuming that's where it is hosted). I would look at your authentication settings for the site

Comment: I've attempted to configure it, however I've come across something called htdocs?

The server structure I am provided with is public_html, with no htdocs folder...?! Would this potentially be the problem? I'm using the wrong directory?

Comment: If your test setup doesn't match your live setup then I guess it could be a problem. httpdocs is usually where the web server looks for the html files to serve

Comment: `public_html` is a common folder for serving webpages. Just as `htdocs` or `wwwroot`, and numerous more. This should not be a problem, unless you place your code in a parent directory. Then you might have to change a reference from `public_html` to `htdocs`.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the info. I thought maybe public_html was linux based.

Comment: Speaking in general terms, it is. But hey, it's also just a name for a folder. And PHP also runs on Windows ;).

Comment: Thanks for your help - much appreciated, I've since got hosting elsewhere and that seems to have done the trick, so I think the problem was down to the host's configuration.